# Module Federation with Angular v14 host and v15 remote throws 'inject() must be called from an injection context' error - how to resolve?

Tags: angular, webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation

Module Federation:

I'm using module federation to load remotes into my host and I have intentionally have version mismatch. The host is using Angular v14 and remotes are using Angular v15. Since there is version mismatch, when I try to load the remotes into the host, I get below error

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `EnvironmentInjector#runInContext`

Host Webpack configuration

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      remotes: {
        "mfe1": "http://localhost:4510/remoteEntry.js",    
      },
      shared: share({
        "@angular/core": { 
          singleton: false,
          strictVersion: true,
          requiredVersion: 'auto',
          includeSecondaries: true },
        "@angular/common": { 
          singleton: false,
          strictVersion: true,
          requiredVersion: 'auto',
          includeSecondaries: true },
        "@angular/router": { 
          singleton: false,
          strictVersion: true,
          requiredVersion: 'auto',
          includeSecondaries: true },
        "@angular/common/http": { 
          singleton: false,
          strictVersion: true,
          requiredVersion: 'auto',
          includeSecondaries: true }, 
      })
    })
  ]
};
```

Remote Webpack config

```
/* eslint-env es6 */
const {
  withModuleFederationPlugin,
  share,
} = require("@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack");

module.exports = withModuleFederationPlugin({
  name: "website-remote",
  filename: "remoteEntry.js",
  exposes: {
    "./Module": "./src/features/fabricated/fabricated.module.ts",
  },

  shared: share({
    "@angular/core": {
      singleton: false,
      strictVersion: true,
      requiredVersion: 'auto',
      includeSecondaries: true,
    },
    "@angular/common": {
      singleton: false,
      strictVersion: true,
      requiredVersion: 'auto',
      includeSecondaries: true,
    },
    "@angular/router": {
      singleton: false,
      strictVersion: true,
      requiredVersion: 'auto',
      includeSecondaries: true,
    },
    "@angular/common/http": {
      singleton: false,
      strictVersion: true,
      requiredVersion: 'auto',
      includeSecondaries: true
    }, 
    "client-auth": {
      singleton: false,
      strictVersion: true,
      requiredVersion: 'auto',
      includeSecondaries: true,
    },
    "@ngxs/store": {
      singleton: false,
      strictVersion: true,
      requiredVersion: 'auto',
      includeSecondaries: true,
    },
  }),
});
```

I tried all the combinations for the shared as suggested in the documentation and other articles. I want understand this error in context with module federation and try to solve it keeping the versioning difference.